# Can I reference FSharp.Data version >= 4.0 on .NetFramework 4.8?

Tags: .net, f#, f#-data, .net-4.8

My project runs on .NetFramework 4.8, and is (among other packages) dependant on FSharp.Data 3.3.3.

I am trying to upgrade the package, but i get the error:

```
*Error FS3031: The type provider '\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\netstandard2.0\FSharp.Data.dll' reported an error: Assembly attribute 'TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' refers to a designer assembly 'FSharp.Data.DesignTime' which cannot be loaded or doesn't exist. Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

*FSC : error FS3031: The type provider 'G:\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\netstandard2.0\FSharp.Data.dll' reported an error: Assembly attribute 'TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' refers to a designer assembly 'FSharp.Data.DesignTime' which cannot be loaded or doesn't exist. Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. [G:\Kernel\Project\Project.Tests.fsproj]*
```

I notice that for FSharp.Data version >= 4.0 the package is build for .NetStandard2.0, but as far as i understand, that shouldn't be an issue.

The 3.3.3 version compiles for me, both the net45 version, and the nestandard2.0 verison in the package.

I use paket for my packages.

I've tried to reference FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll, but with no luck.

.fsproj:

```xml
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>46274688-4815-444d-b237-9aeec92ef3e6</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Project.Tests</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Project.Tests</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Name>Project.Tests</Name>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <TargetFSharpCoreVersion>6.0.0.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

The app.config of the project looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
  
<runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <Paket>True</Paket>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding></runtime></configuration>
```

I might be missing something obvious, but i've tried to google this for a few days now.
Has anyone had any success using this package on .NetFramework 4.8?

Comment: Did you find anything? I have the same issue with a .net core 3.1 F# project. I get the error if I reference Fsharp.Data >= 4.0.0. 3.3.3 compiles fine.

Comment: I found this article: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/7470. See this comment: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/7470#issuecomment-526815073

Comment: Sadly not. We were using the old msbuildTools-style .fsproj. Given the answer below, i am now trying to convert to sdk-style .fsproj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new console app using .NET Framework 4.8 and FSharp.Data 4.2.3 with no problem.

I noticed that you're redirecting to FSharp.Core 6.0.0. Are you sure you want that?

Anyway, my .fsproj is:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework> 

    <WarnOn>3390;$(WarnOn)</WarnOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="4.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And there is no app.config.